# What RoR programs are used in this tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal

I'm new to rails, and I'm watching this video tutorial online and I was wondering what programs are being using - I recognize terminal, but thats about it.

http://media.rubyonrails.org/video/rails_take2_with_sound.mov

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the video is from 2005, and most of it looks horribly out of date.

- Safari
- [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net), which fell out of favor when Leopard's built-in Terminal got tabs
- [TextMate](http://www.macromates.com)
- [CocoaMySQL](http://cocoamysql.sourceforge.net/), which has been superseded by [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/)

Comment: I'm a little scared of a world where most of what was used in 2005 is horribly out of date.

Comment: Well, for one thing, it was filmed on OS X Tiger, and OS X Leopard got a big visual makeover when it was released in 2007. I did say "looks" out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal, Safari (browser) and TextMate (editor)